# How to condense a sparse matrix efficiently

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

In Python, for my application it is usually best to create a sparse matrix by creating a sparse COO matrix with rows, columns and values arrays and then changing it to CSC (CSR) format.

Now, say I want to condense the CSC matrix. What is an efficient way to do so? The condensation rows/columns vary during the code and are much smaller than the dimensions of the sparse matrix, so I do not believe rebuilding the COO matrix is efficient.

The following MWE shows an example for creating the condensed matrix, but without any optimization attempts. There is a sparse efficiency warning because the number of nonzeros is increased. In this MWE I use `dia_array` to create the sparse matrix for simplicity.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import dia_array

def main():
    n = 10
    m = 6
    data = np.tile(np.concatenate((np.arange(1, m+1),
                                   np.arange(m-1, 0, -1)))[:, np.newaxis], (1, n))
    offsets = np.arange(-m+1, m)
    A = dia_array((data, offsets), shape=(n, n)).tocsc()
    print("Matrix A:")
    print(repr(A.toarray()))

    # condense these rows/columns
    cond_rowscols = np.arange(n-8, n, 2)
    print("Condensed rows/columns of A:")
    print(repr(cond_rowscols))

    # IMPROVE HERE
    # condensation algorithm
    B = A.copy()
    B[[cond_rowscols[0]]] += B[cond_rowscols[1:]].sum(axis=0)
    B[:, [cond_rowscols[0]]] += B[:, cond_rowscols[1:]].sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
    free_rowscols = np.ones(n, dtype=bool)
    free_rowscols[cond_rowscols[1:]] = False
    B = B[np.ix_(free_rowscols, free_rowscols)]

    print("Condensed matrix A:")
    print(repr(B.toarray()))

    print('Done')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The output is:

```
Matrix A:
array([[6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [5, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0],
       [3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 3],
       [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]])
Condensed rows/columns of A:
array([2, 4, 6, 8])
Condensed matrix A:
array([[ 6,  5,  6,  3,  1,  0,  0],
       [ 5,  6,  9,  4,  2,  0,  0],
       [ 6,  9, 56, 14, 16, 14,  9],
       [ 3,  4, 14,  6,  4,  2,  0],
       [ 1,  2, 16,  4,  6,  4,  2],
       [ 0,  0, 14,  2,  4,  6,  4],
       [ 0,  0,  9,  0,  2,  4,  6]])
Done
```

---

Edit: As per hpaulj's comment, we can create a condensation matrix `T`:

```py
    # condensation with matrix multiplication
    n_conds = cond_rowscols.shape[0]  # number of condensed rows/cols
    t_vals = np.ones(n, dtype=int)
    t_rows = np.arange(n)
    t_cols = np.empty_like(t_rows)
    t_cols[free_rowscols] = np.arange(n-n_conds+1)
    t_cols[cond_rowscols[1:]] = cond_rowscols[0]
    T = csc_array((t_vals, (t_rows, t_cols)), shape=(n, n-n_conds+1))
```

Such that the condensed matrix A is `B = T.T @ A @ T`.
T is:

```py
>>>print(repr(T.toarray()))
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]], dtype=int32)
```

This does not yield any sparse efficiency errors! I still have to time it, though, for larger problems. Does `scipy.sparse` use sparse BLAS for sparse matrix multiplications?

Comment: Could you explain the condensing logic simply?  The best tool for manipulating sparse matrices is matrix multiplication.  The code uses this to sum rows or columns, and to index/slice.  In other words, it creates a selection/extractor matrix (or 2) and multiplies. Can your condensation be cast as a matrix multiplication?

Comment: Thank you @hpaulj, I have updated the question with your suggestion. The idea is that all of the rows and columns of `A` of index `cond_rowscols[1:]` should be added into the rows and columns of `A` of index `cond_rowscols[0]`, respectively.

Comment: You can explore the sparse matrix multiplication code.  Last I looked it used a documented algorithm (some 1990's math journal article), that involves two calls to compiled code (cython).  Some have been able to link in some MKL library.

Comment: I have found [the github page](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/b5d8bab88af61d61de09641243848df63380a67f/scipy/sparse/sparsetools/csr.h) of the sparse multiplication algorithm. The CSC matrix uses a transpose of the CSR matrix algorithm. Also, here is the [article which it is based on](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02070824), from 1993. I really don't think I can beat them lol.

Comment: Matrix multiplication for sparse matrices uses `M._mul_sparse_matrix(other)`, which calls a couple of functions from `_sparsetools.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`.  One returns `nnz`, the number of nonzeros in the result.  This is used initial `indptr, indices, data` arrays, which are passed to the 2nd function.  The result matrix is created from that.

Comment: But I thought there was some logic that could be used to alter `A.values`, `A.indices` and `A.indptr` directly, since `A` has canonical format (i.e. no duplicates and `A.indices` with sorted values.

Comment: I believe sparse matrices are developed for linear algebra problems like finite differences and finite element models.  The summing of duplicates when converting `coo` to `csr` is particularly helpful when creating a stiffness matrix for FEM.

Comment: (Btw, I'm getting a "move this discussion to chat" suggestion.) Yes, I followed the `_sparsetools` files and found a C++ function written in a header file, the previously linked github website (lines 515 to 669 inside `csr.h`). And yes, my matrix comes from an FEM problem. The issue is that I have to change the sparsity pattern via condensation every now and again, solving different, but similar, FE problems, AFTER converting from `COO` to `CSR/CSC`. The condensation imposes an equality constraint in the unknowns of the linear system.

Comment: Is `A` always symmetric?

Comment: Yes, `A` is always symmetric

Comment: `mkl_sparse_sypr` from the MKL library is `C = B.T @ A @ B` if `A` is symmetric. It's substantially more optimized than the scipy C extensions (it gets you threading, for example).

Comment: Thanks. I made a cython wrapper on MKL Pardiso. I might make one for the function you mentioned as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a test case for both options shown in the MWE with a simple performance comparison, using a smaller set of values than I intend to use in practice.

It seems that the in-place sum option takes about 5 times more than the multiplication option.

Since solving linear systems is always much more expensive, I think I'll settle with the sparse matrix multiplication option, for now.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import dia_array, csr_array
from time import perf_counter

def build_sp_mat(n=None, m=None):
    """Generates a square sparse CSC matrix of size `n` and half bandwidth `m`"""
    if n is None:
        n = 1_000  # matrix size
    if m is None:
        m = 50  # half bandwidth
    data = np.tile(np.concatenate((np.arange(1, m+1),
                                   np.arange(m-1, 0, -1)))[:, np.newaxis], (1, n))
    offsets = np.arange(-m+1, m)
    A = dia_array((data, offsets), shape=(n, n)).tocsc()
    return A

def condensed_rowscols(n, n_conds=None):
    """"Returns the indices of the condensed rows/columns
    Also returns a boolean mask of the non-condensed rows/columns
    """
    if n_conds is None:
        n_conds = 50  # total number of condensed rows/columns
    # condense these rows/columns
    cond_rowscols = np.arange(n//n_conds-1, n, n//n_conds)
    free_rowscols = np.ones(n, dtype=bool)
    free_rowscols[cond_rowscols[1:]] = False
    print(repr(cond_rowscols))
    return cond_rowscols, free_rowscols

def condense_in_place_sum(A, cond_rowscols, free_rowscols):
    """Performs condensation via a sum of the condensed rows and columns"""
    A[[cond_rowscols[0]]] += A[cond_rowscols[1:]].sum(axis=0)
    A[:, [cond_rowscols[0]]] += A[:, cond_rowscols[1:]].sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
    Acond = A[np.ix_(free_rowscols, free_rowscols)]  # indices are sorted
    return Acond

def condense_mat_mult(A, cond_rowscols, free_rowscols, n, n_conds):
    """Performs condensation via sparse matrix multiplications"""
    t_vals = np.ones(n, dtype=int)
    t_rows = np.arange(n)
    t_cols = np.empty_like(t_rows)
    t_cols[free_rowscols] = np.arange(n-n_conds+1)
    t_cols[cond_rowscols[1:]] = cond_rowscols[0]
    T = csr_array((t_vals, (t_rows, t_cols)), shape=(n, n-n_conds+1))
    Acond = T.T @ A @ T
    Acond.sort_indices()  # indices have to be sorted
    return Acond, T


if __name__ == "__main__":
    n, m, n_conds = 500_000, 54, 1000
    A = build_sp_mat(n, m)
    cond_rowscols, free_rowscols = condensed_rowscols(n, n_conds)

    A.sort_indices()  # this is important

    B = A.copy()
    stime = perf_counter()
    Acond1 = condense_in_place_sum(B, cond_rowscols, free_rowscols)
    print(f"Condensation via in-place sum took {perf_counter()-stime} s")
    # Acond1 comes with its indices array sorted automatically

    stime = perf_counter()
    Acond2, _ = condense_mat_mult(A, cond_rowscols, free_rowscols, n, n_conds)
    print(f"Condensation via sparse multiplication took {perf_counter()-stime} s")
    # Acond2's indices array has to be sorted, as shown in the function

    print("Done")
```

The output is

```
Condensation via in-place sum took 9.0079096 s
Condensation via sparse multiplication took 1.4657909 s
Done
```